# Does moving apps to internal sd storage move the app save data as well?

Tags: 6.0-marshmallow, internal-storage, external-sd, app2sd, internal-sd

I am just wondering. Lets say I move the game "Cooking Mama" to the adopted internal SD storage. The game is says 73.21 mb after the move. Does that include the game saves and downloaded content or just the original app and all my save data are in my phone still.

Answer (score 1):

Game saves are usually in the `/data` partition and will not be affected by app storage movement.

Downloaded content are usually in `Android/data` or `Android/obb` in your storage and is likely to be moved as well.

Comment: On my device, I found an obb file at **/storage/emulated/obb**, which seems to correspond to the external SD. The obb inside **Android/obb** has the same checksum as the other, so I guess it's some kind of link.

Answer (score 0):

if you are moving apk files, then yes they are standalone, and only useful when you need to reinstall on another android os, repair or downgrade the app. They are safe to move. Only move apk that you installed and not came with original os.